# Inserting a new record: Row gets created in database but values do not get submitted

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, x-editable

So after I click the submit button a new row is created in my database with a userID but the username does not get submitted to the database. Currently my loginInfo table I am submitting two has 3 columns: userID (auto generated and incremented), username, and password. I believe my error is in the newuser.php file I am unsure of what to do in it.

```
<td><a href="#" class="myeditable editable editable-click editable-empty" id="new_username" data-type="text" data-name="name" data-original-title="Enter username">Empty</a></td>
```

Also in the same file under scripts

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

//init editables
$('.myeditable').editable({
    url: 'post.php' //this url will not be used for creating new user, it is only for update
});

//make username required
$('#new_username').editable('option', 'validate', function(v) {
    if(!v) return 'Required field name!';
});

//automatically show next editable
$('.myeditable').on('save.newuser', function(){
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(that).closest('tr').next().find('.myeditable').editable('show');
    }, 200);
});

$('#save-btn').click(function() {
    $('.myeditable').editable('submit', {
        url: 'newuser.php',
        ajaxOptions: {
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json' //assuming json response
        },
        success: function(data, config) {
            if(data && data.id) {  //record created, response like {"id": 2}
                //set pk
                $(this).editable('option', 'pk', data.id);
                //remove unsaved class
                $(this).removeClass('editable-unsaved');
                //show messages
                var msg = 'New user created! Now editables submit individually.';
                $('#msg').addClass('alert-success').removeClass('alert-error').html(msg).show();
                $('#save-btn').hide();
                $(this).off('save.newuser');
            } else if(data && data.errors){
                //server-side validation error, response like {"errors": {"username": "username already exist"} }
                config.error.call(this, data.errors);
            }
        },
        error: function(errors) {
            var msg = '';
            if(errors && errors.responseText) { //ajax error, errors = xhr object
                msg = errors.responseText;
            } else { //validation error (client-side or server-side)
                $.each(errors, function(k, v) { msg += k+": "+v+"<br>"; });
            }
            $('#msg').removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-error').html(msg).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Post.php

```
include('connect.php'); 
sleep(1);
$pk = $_post['pk'];
$un=$_POST['name'];
$value1 = $_POST['value'];

if(!empty($value1)) {
    $sql =("UPDATE loginInfo
            SET $un=$value1
            WHERE userID='$pk'");
    mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    //here, for debug reason we just return dump of $_POST, you will see result in browser console
    print_r($_POST);
}
else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
    echo "This field is required!";
}
```

newuser.php

```
$pk = $_post['pk'];
$un=$_POST['name'];
$value1 = $_POST['value'];

try {

    $sql =("INSERT INTO loginInfo(username,password)
            VALUES ('a','b')");   
    mysqli_query($con, $sql);


} catch (Exception $e) {
    print($e->__toString());
}

?>
```

In my firefox under the net console I see this output which is the value I entered into the name textbox

```
Parameters
name    
testing

Source
name=testing
```

docs from the website: https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#newrecord

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around the username, since it's a string.

```
$sql =("UPDATE loginInfo
        SET $un='$value1'
        WHERE userID='$pk'");
```

It would be better if you used a prepared query, to prevent SQL injection.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, 
                        "UPDATE loginInfo
                        SET $un = ?
                        WHERE userID = ?");
mysqli_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $value1, $pk);
mysqli_execute($stmt);
```

Since the column name can't be parametrized, you should validate `$un` before using it in the query. Or you could just hard-code the column name rather than using the POST parameter, if this is the only column the user can update.

Comment: Thanks I changed my code but its still not working. I don't think I have my post.php and newuser.php pages set up correctly. I cant hardcode the column name because the user can update many columns

Comment: Is the query getting an error? What does `echo mysqli_error($con);` show?

Comment: I just noticed that I left out the `$con` argument to `mysqli_prepare`, so try the corrected syntax.